# Why no zoom lenses with a maximum aperture wider than f/2.8?

Tags: lens, aperture, zoom

I can understand that a zoom lens with a maximum aperture wider than f/2.8 would be difficult and costly, but it seems like something pros would kill for.  Surely it can't be more expensive (if its possible) than some of the $10k+ lenses and they exist to sell in limited quantities.  Is it just near impossible or is there another reason we don't see zoom lenses faster than f/2.8?

Comment: Olympus makes an [f/2.0 zoom for Four Thirds](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/404517-REG/Olympus_261012_35_100mm_f_2_0_ED_Zuiko.html), although arguably the smaller sensor format means an f/4 lens is a more apt comparison on full-frame.

Comment: Weight and cost are the biggest reasons.

Comment: I have to suspect that the number of element & groups plays a part, as well -- inasmuch as each of these elements contributes to the amount of light the lens can transmit, at some level, the increased count typically seen in zooms would seem to be a factor.

Comment: Sigma now makes a full frame 24-35mm f2.0 zoom lens! http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Sigma-24-35mm-f-2-DG-HSM-Art-Lens.aspx

Comment: Check out the brand new Canon RF 28-70mm f/2L USM Lens! It makes your question somewhat obsolete ;-)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[Angenieux](http://www.angenieux.com/zoom-lenses/index.php?txt=5) (for one) makes some f/2 zooms. They're used primarily for movie making. The [Optimo 17-80](http://www.angenieux.com/file/datasheets/cinema/pdf_Catalogue_2011-2012/17-80_catalog_2011.pdf), for example, is an f/2 (T2.2) lens, covering, obviously enough, the 17-80mm range.

As for why these aren't common, consider that this particular lens weighs 11 pounds and costs about $50,000US.

Going even more extreme would be the [Optimo 24-290](http://www.angenieux.com/file/datasheets/cinema/pdf_Catalogue_2011-2012/24-290_catalog_2011.pdf), which is f/2.5 (T2.8), and constant aperture across that entire range. It weighs 24 pounds, and though I don't know a price on this one, I think: "more than most houses I've lived in" would be a safe guess.

Yes, you undoubtedly could build an f/2 zoom that was smaller, lighter, and less expensive, especially if you restricted it to APS-C. Nonetheless, this may give some idea of the direction really fast zooms would go. Yes, they can be considerably more than expensive than $10K, and they can be unreasonably large and heavy as well.

From an optical viewpoint, it largely comes down to correcting aberrations. Just for example, for any particular design spherical aberration grows approximately quadratically with aperture.

Along with that, you run into size and weight problems: to get one stop faster, you multiply the diameter by ~1.4. That doubles the area, which multiplies the volume of each element by 2.8. With each element weighing about three times as much, the mechanical parts to mount those elements end up bigger and heavier as well.

So, let's consider one of the most popular fast zoom categories: the 70-200 f/2.8. Most current ones way about 3 pounds. Based on simple geometry, scaling up to f/2 should increase the weight to about 9 pounds. At 3 pounds, you're right at the border between hand holding and really wishing for a monopod. At 9 pounds, most people pretty nearly need a tripod for any more than one or two shots at a time.

Along with that, 9 pound lenses just don't sell in large quantities. Reasonably dedicated photographers buy a lot of 3 pound lenses (including the aforementioned 70-200/2.8). When you get to the 5-6 pound lenses like a 300/2.8, the quantity has already dropped a *lot* -- only a few of the most dedicated will even consider them. Going up a step from there (e.g., to a 400/2.8) the number drops precipitously.

Let me try to put that drop into perspective. When I go to one of my kids' sporting events, chances are pretty good at least three or four of the parents will have a 70-200/2.8, or something around the same size/weight (and at a larger event, I might easily see a dozen).

For 300/2.8, that drops a lot. On any given weekend at my local photo-friendly wildlife refuge, I might or might not see one. During mating season (for example) seeing two or three wouldn't be all that unusual.

In twenty years of shooting, I could probably just about count on my fingers the total number of times I've seen people out shooting a 400/2.8, 500/4, 600/4, etc.

Based just on size and weight, a 70-200 f/2 would be pretty much in that last category -- so rare it would hardly be used even if somebody put it in their catalog.

Zoom/varifocal lenses with larger relative apertures do become more practical (and common) when dealing with shorter focal lengths and/or only needing to cover smaller sensors. Olympus has made f/2 lenses for micro-four thirds cameras for quite a while, Canon has announced (but as I write this, not yet released) a 28-70 f/2 for their new EOS r mount, and (perhaps craziest of all) the old Minolta 3x-1x Macro zoom, with a geometric aperture varying from f/1.7 to f/2.8 (but at 3x, the geometric f/1.7 aperture is effectively reduced to f/6.7--and you usually stop down from there, to try to get at least a tenth of a millimeter of depth of field...

Comment: Is that cinema lens in f-stops or t-stops? Cinema lenses are often rated for transmission rather than maximum aperture, and quite often a t-stop of 2 requires a wider f-stop, so that lens might actually be f/1.8 or wider. It should also be noted that many of the really expensive cinema lenses have CONSTANT apertures throughout their very wide zoom ranges.

Comment: @jrista: It's f/2, T/2.2, and yes, it's constant aperture.

Comment: But why?  I think that's the question - why must a zoom lens be so much bigger, heavier and expensive than a fixed focal length lens?  Something to do with the number of elements, transmission of light?  Or that at that price you don't want to compromise on IQ?

Comment: A bit of googling shows a Optimo 24-290 going for around $60k. (http://web.me.com/paulraimondi/Arri_435_For_Sale/Pictures/Pages/Optimo.html) It wasn't clear to me if this was new or used.

Comment: @PaulCezanne: I'm not sure, but I'd have to guess that's used.

Comment: @MikeW exactly...and using cine lenses as a comparison for price...aren't they usually more expensive in general?

Comment: If you want to see people using 500/4's or similar you probably need to change the times you're looking.  What you're describing at that point is functionally equivalent to a large refracting telescope.  After dark at large regional star parties is probably your best bet; although even there they'll be uncommon.

Comment: @DanNeely: I've yet to see such a thing at a star party. Refractors are pretty rare to start with, and those I do see are mostly the usual suspects: Celestron, Meade, Orion, Vixen, Televue, one home-built job, etc., not anything like a Nikon or Canon with (for example) a controllable aperture.

Comment: The places to see the 400mm, 500mm, and 600mm lenses are on the sidelines at world-class sporting events: The NFL, Olympics, World Cup, Formula 1, etc.

Comment: The places where you won't see them, even when they are there, are where they are being used by the CIA, Mousaad, KGB, etc. LOL

Comment: And the number of users employing them in those situations are totally dwarfed by the number of folks using the more commonly seen lenses. For every NFL game played there are 10-15 college games and 10s of thousands of high school and youth league games played. For every world class soccer game played there are probably at least 100,000 organized soccer games played.

Comment: So, this is years ago... but the new eos r 28-70mm F2 lens bears mentioning here;  and it's only 3 pounds!

Comment: Thanks for updating this answer from the stone ages! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Olympus makes f/2 zooms, but I disagree with another poster who said this was like f/4 because of the smaller sensor size.

Sure, the size of the sensor has an impact on ultimate image quality, particularly with depth-of-field effects, but you still get to shoot an f/2 in lighting that would be impossible with an f/4.

I don't see any postings sneering at the cited cine f/2 lenses, although they surely have a smaller "sensor" than 35mm full-frame, as well!

Comment: I'm not sneering. For DoF, see [this](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10079/). For low-light: The twice-the-area full-frame sensor format theoretically allows twice the light to be gathered overall, and I think it's generally safe to say that full-frame cameras have a one-stop noise advantage over four-thirds — same as f/2 to f/4. Note the crop-factor correspondence of the focal length the Olympus lens I linked, too: it's a 35-100mm, giving a field of view roughly like the traditional 70-200mm.

Comment: I can see that full-frame confers a noise advantage, but I think you missed my point that it confers **no** shutter-speed advantage.

Comment: Same thing — if you can go up a stop in ISO for the same image quality, you can use a faster shutter.

Comment: In this context we have to treat m43 f/2 as FF f/2 equivalent - the question was about the f/2 zoom feasibility, and yes, if the Olympus zoom is scaled 2x we would get the f/2 FF zoom (having 4x more aperture area and 8x the weight)

Comment: The size of the entrance pupil, which defines the minimum diameter of the front element also does not change with sensor/image circle size. But the focal length needed to get the same field of view *does* change. If you only need 1/2 the focal length, then for the same f-number you only need half the diameter and 1/8 the weight.

Comment: Um, I actually do know that f/2 to f/4 is two stops. But I think the general point still basically applies. :)

Comment: Sorry, had to downvote. 50mm f/2 is equivalent to 100mm f/4 if the crop factor is 2. ISO 100 with a crop-2 camera is equivalent to ISO 400 on a FF camera. The conversions are: multiply focal length and aperture by crop factor, multiply ISO with crop factor squared.