# Why don't my calculations based on a crop factor of 1.5 work for the Nikon P1000?

Tags: lens, crop-factor, aps-c

I know that Nikon cameras APS-C sensors has a crop factor of 1.5 but if we apply this to calculate the equivalent focal lenght in 35mm format for the Nikon P1000 camera we will not get the exact values mentionned in the specifications.

> Focal lenght is **4.3mm** to **539mm**
>
> Equivalent Focal Lenght is **24mm** to **3000mm**

3000/539= **5.58** This is not the 1.5 crop Factor of APS-C sensors of Nikon cameras.

Comment: You are correct. The Nikon P1000 does not have an APS-C sensor. Did you have a question, or just this observation?

Comment: That was a question i did not understand the crop multiplication as i thought P1000 has 1.5 crop factor because i think i have read in some comments P1000 has APS-C sensor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The P1000 unfortunately isn't an APS-C, it's far smaller at 1/2.3-inch, which gives it a crop factor of 5.6.

Compared to a 35mm sensor it is tiny.

From [ApoTelyt.com - Nikon P1000 Comparison Review](https://www.apotelyt.com/compare-camera/nikon-p1000-review)

> The Nikon P1000 features a 1/2.3-inch sensor and has a format factor (sometimes also referred to as "crop factor") of 5.6. Within the spectrum of camera sensors, this places the Nikon P1000 among the smaller-sensor digicams that favor affordability and compact design.

[image]

Comment: Thank you i have two questions If the tiny sensor has more megapixels will this make the crop factor even bigger ? And how they calculate the crop factor if we take these values in the picture 864mm² and 28mm² ? What is the name of the sensor used in P1000  if not APS-C ?

Comment: The name is unimportant, just call it a 1/2.3" & then avoid it like the plague. I had my eye on this camera until I discovered there are phones with bigger sensors. There's a whole lot of physics which frankly I don't understand - though there are many here who do - which basically says 'tiny sensor == bad picture'.

Comment: @Tetsujin 'tiny sensor == bad picture' - in low light? Maybe (depends on quantum efficiency, algorithms,...). In good light? Not necessarily.

Comment: @P.Kod Megapixel have nothing to do with crop factor - it simply refers to the size of the sensor. See [the field-of-view tag's information text](https://photo.stackexchange.com/tags/field-of-view/info) for further information.

Comment: I think i figured out how the crop factor is calculated. A square is told to be two times bigger than another if the diagonal is 2x bigger, so they just divide the diameter of the 35mm film into the diameter of the sensor in question, here the diagonal of 35 mm film is 43,26mm and the diameter of P1000 sensor is 7,666, so 43,26/7,66= 5,55, the problem is that the two sensors doesn't have the same ratio so i don't know how to resolve it exactly with mathematics if someone knows how it would be great.

Comment: @P.Kod as stated above, just look at [the field-of-view tag's information text](https://photo.stackexchange.com/tags/field-of-view/info). Usually, we are talking about diagonal field of view - but you know what? The question of how to account for changes in aspect ratio in this formula would be perfectly on-topic as its own question. If you don't ask it, I will. ;-)

Comment: @flolilolilo Ok i will see that, it's interesting you can ask the question ;)

Comment: @P.Kod Never mind, I found this: [What is the crop factor for Four Thirds cameras considering aspect ratios?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/24642/what-is-the-crop-factor-for-four-thirds-cameras-considering-aspect-ratios)

Comment: @flolilolilo That question is a good one but the answer doesn't give clear explanations of calculation. In my previous comment i said wrongly diameter instead of diagonal how i can correct that i see no edit function.

Comment: A 24 to 3000mm equivalent for APS-C would probably be the size, weight and cost of a TV studio box lens :)

Answer (score 6):

It is simply that the P1000 does not offer an APS-C sensor - as [its manual](http://download.nikonimglib.com/archive3/gibeG00yANMD03LIyPK66rJEEw81/P1000RM_(En)04.pdf#page=232) and [marketing site](https://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/coolpix/p/p1000/spec.htm) state it has a `1/2.3"` sensor, which offers a crop factor of `~5.5`.