# Is maximum focal length of P1000 similar to 300mm kit lens provided with APS-C cameras?

Tags: focal-length

Is maximum focal length of P1000 similar to 300mm kit lens provided with APS-C cameras? Either in terms of 35mm or 1/2.3(sensor size found in P1000) format.

Comment: It's **3,000**mm equivalent, not 300. See https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/112177/57929 and https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/101621/57929

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, I know that, but I thought since decrease in sensor size is proportional to increase in focal length, maybe the reverse will be true, if a smaller sensor size has 3000mm focal length, the APS-C might achieve the same result, if I crop the image.

Comment: If you're going to crop the image, then so long as you stand in the same place any crop will be equivalent visually no matter the camera's crop factor, sensor size or lens [except for number of pixels]. This actually has nothing to do with the length of the lens, this is pure physics, perspective.  See https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/97747/57929 for a beginner's guide to crop factor vs perspective.

Answer (score 4):

No they are not similar. They are not even close.

The Nikon P1000 has an actual focal length of 4.3-539mm and a crop factor of 5.56 which yields a 24-**3000mm** equivalent focal length.

A Nikon APS-C camera with a 300mm lens has a crop factor of 1.5 which yields a **450mm** equivalent focal length.

Comment: The words and terminology get confusing as people often use one word but mean another. In this case the **literal** question was about **focal length**. The P1000 is 539mm and the 300 is 300mm. The apparent image sizes due to crop factors are as you stated 3000mm & 450mm equivalents to 35mm reference. I think you answered the intent of the question.